# how to validate from UIButton addtarget to a different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm adding a `UIButton` to a view on a different `UIViewController`. I need the target selector to point to that view controller from json value

```
- (IBAction)timeline:(id)sender {

    if ([_NoTimeline isEqualToString:@"timeline not available :)"]) {
        NearmeNOViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NONearmeViewController"];

        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        NearmeFrendViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NearmeFrendViewController"];

        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem now? Its not presenting view controller?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR yes Its not presenting view controller and i have error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]:

Comment: What's the type of _NoTimeline?

Comment: @JanApotheker _NoTimeline is value from json

Comment: Show the code how you are assigning value to `_NoTimeline`

Comment: @RajeshkumarR @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *NoTimeline; parsing from json NSDictionary *dictionary = responseObject;
        self.NoTimeline = dictionary[@"timeline"];

Comment: `NSLog` `self.NoTimeline` and paste here.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR if user with no timeline "timeline not available :)" , but if user has add timeline "timeline =     (
                {
            comment = 0;
            "id_timeline" = 62;
            "id_user" = 13;
            "kategori_timeline" = Traveling;
            likes = 0;
            "lokasi_timeline" = "AUTOBRIDAL";
            "name_user" = "budi";
            "pic_timeline" = "";
            "status_timeline" = "otw with high traffic";
            "with_timeline" = 0;
        },"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are assigning `NSString` `"timeline not available :)"` to variable `self.NoTimeline` if timeline isnt available. And assigning an `NSArray` to variable `self.NoTimeline`. If you can edit your api add status key properly. If not try this

```
- (IBAction)timeline:(id)sender{

if ([self.NoTimeline isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NearmeNOViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NONearmeViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
} 
else {
    NearmeFrendViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NearmeFrendViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that _NoTimeline is not always of type NSString. Therefore the isEqualToString: operation fails.

You can check for NSString by using:

```
if ([_NoTimeline isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] {
   // Your code
}
```